# pass cmsfn value to a scope variable angularjs

Tags: angularjs, freemarker, magnolia

I'm trying to pass a variable to angularjs from `cmsfn`. Did anyone managed to do it already?

```
    <div ng-controller="someController">
        [#assign currentNode = cmsfn.asJCRNode(content)]
        [#assign rootPageNode = cmsfn.root(currentNode, "mgnl:page")!]
       <div style="display: none">{{myVar='${rootPageNode}'}}</div>
    </div>
```

In the above code, when i try to use `myVar` in angular, its value is empty.

Comment: For this code to work, it needs to go through the rendering engine. It should work just fine if above snippet is in the `.ftl` file, but not if it is directly in the `.js` file that is part of resources. Where is your file located and what is it, resource or template?

Comment: it's a template and the file is in pages folder,inside other sources, i'm trying to get the page's name to access to page's properties through the page's name. if you know other way to do it, feel free to say something

Comment: Then it should work as it is already. BTW you can skip the first line. `root()` method accepts both `ContentMap` or `Node` as parameter. One possible explanation for your issue is that you are passing in the page that is already root of the site (i.e. top level page w/o any parent), in that case method would return null.

Comment: rootPageNode has the page's name, but i dont know how to send the value to angular, it appear undefined, how can i access to myVar? $scope.myVar? should i declare it globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, reduce your FM code to single line:

```
 [#assign rootPage = cmsfn.root(content, "mgnl:page")!]
```

This way, what you get back is still `ContentMap` and not `Node` which is easier to manipulate in the template.

Second, get the name of the page (if that is what you want):

```
${rootPage.@name}
```

You can find list of other special properties of content map at the bottom of [this page](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/JCR+API)

Now, last about the angular part, what you have in your template is just angular expression, "print statement" if you will, which will not assign variable. You need to do the assignment using `$scope.myVar=...` in the `someController` controller itself. Which means that the .js file itself needs to be freemarker template.